# Simple Pokemon battle

Tags: java

Good day. I am having problems with the Enemy HP on my code as it doesn't decrease to 0, but instead just keeps adding the damages I've dealt with each attack I chose and shows something like this (Pikachu uses Thunder! Enemy Life:-120). I'm new to Java and I'm having trouble identifying the problem. If anyone can help me, please and thank you!

```
import java.io.*;

public class Pokemon extends Formulas
{
public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException
    {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    Formulas f = new Formulas();

    String opt, ans;
    int EnemyHP = 100;

    do
    {
        System.out.println("What will Pikachu do? \nA) Thundershock \nB) Quick Attack \nC) Thundershock \nD) Thunder");
        opt = br.readLine();

            switch(opt)
                {
                case "a": case "A":
                    f.setThundershock();
                    System.out.println("Pikachu uses Thundershock! Enemy Life:"+f.getThundershock());
                    break;
                case "b": case "B":
                    f.setQuickAttack();
                    System.out.println("Pikachu uses Quick Attack! Enemy Life:"+f.getQuickAttack());
                    break;
                case "c": case "C":
                    f.setThunderbolt();
                    System.out.println("Pikachu uses Thunderbolt! Enemy Life:"+f.getThunderbolt());
                    break;
                case "d": case "D":
                    f.setThunder();
                    System.out.println("Pikachu uses Thunder! Enemy Life:"+f.getThunder());
                    break;
                default:
                    System.out.println("Invalid input.");
                }
    }
    while (EnemyHP != 0);
}   
}
```

Here is the Formulas class:

```
class Formulas extends SkillValues{

private int Thundershock, QuickAttack, Thunderbolt, Thunder, Damage, EnemyHP;

SkillValues s = new SkillValues();

public void setThundershock()
{
    this.Damage = s.valueThundershock();
    EnemyHP -= Damage;
}
public void setQuickAttack()
{
    this.Damage = s.valueQuickAttack();
    EnemyHP -= Damage;
}
public void setThunderbolt()
{
    this.Damage = s.valueThunderbolt();
    EnemyHP -= Damage;
}
public void setThunder()
{
    this.Damage = s.valueThunder();
    EnemyHP -= Damage;  
}


public int getThundershock()
{
    return EnemyHP;
}
public int getQuickAttack()
{
    return EnemyHP;
}
public int getThunderbolt()
{
    return EnemyHP;
}
public int getThunder()
{
    return EnemyHP;
}
}
```

And lastly the SkillsValue:

```
public class SkillValues 
{

public int valueThundershock()
{
    return 15;
}
public int valueQuickAttack()
{
    return 10;
}
public int valueThunderbolt()
{
    return 15;
}
public int valueThunder()
{
    return 40;
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two `EnemyHP` variables. One is local to the `main` method, which you never update, and thus your loop never ends, and another in the `Formulas` class, which you do update.

Your loop should get the current value from `f`.

Change

```
while (EnemyHP != 0)
```

to

```
while (f.getThunder () >= 0) // you have multiple methods that return the EnemyHP member
                             // but it would make more sense to have a getEnemyHP method
```

You should also initialize the `EnemyHP` member of your `Formulas` class. Otherwise it will be 0 by default.

You can pass it to the constructor :

```
Formulas f = new Formulas(100);

...

class Formulas extends SkillValues{
    ...
    public Formulas (int EnemyHP) {
        this.EnemyHP = EnemyHP;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for the answer. 

However, I came up with another problem and this time, I'm getting "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" on public class Pokemon extends Formulas. I think I've followed your advice well, but I must be doing something wrong. Can you please help me again. Sorry and thanks!